# Use of "still" in a reply in informal conversation

Tags: construction

In informal conversation, in answer to the question, "What happened?" would it be correct to reply, "Nothing still important"? (Meaning nothing that is still important to discuss now; the topic lost its importance).

Comment: If you mean not much that matters to the brewery.

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't use "still" in quite that way. In informal conversation, you could say,

> Nothing that's still important.

You could also say,

> Nothing that's important any more.